# Azure DevOps Kanban board

Tags: azure-devops, azure-boards

What is the reason we can't see Issue work items on a kanban board.  My team isn't a traditional development team and we want to track Stories/bugs/issues separately on the board.  The only way to do this right now is to just use a tag on a User Story to distinguish it from others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a bit of history behind this... The Agile template stems from Microsoft Solution Framework for Agile Software development. The MSF has been renamed and now it's just Agile. The "Issue" is the equivalent of a "Impediment", or something that's hindering the team's process. It's not a "Production Issue" or equivalent.

In Scrum and many other Agile frameworks, the Impediments/Issues are owned by the Scrum Master/Agile Coach and not managed by the Product Owner on the Product Backlog.

If you want a "Production Issue" type work item that lives on the backlog you'll need to:

1. Create an inherited process in the Azure DevOps settings.
2. Add a new work item type for your "Issue"
3. Add the required fields and states for the backlog level you want to integrate with
4. Edit the Backlog Level and add the new work item type

[image]

Optionally disable the old "Issue" work item type.

To move bugs to the Board settings and set the "Bugs are with Requirements":

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is a process reason. Issues, risks, and Impediments are not deliverable items that you can estimate and plan with backlogs. To work with these items, you have to use [queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/using-queries?view=azure-devops). Here is the official explanation: [Manage issues or impediments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/manage-issues-impediments?view=azure-devops).

Comment: You can recreate these work item types under the requirements category or in the bug category to hack around that.